# Copying from like named workbook to named workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding and excel and would greatly appreciate some help. I am trying to copy data from one workbook (whose end of name changes every time it is opened) to a workbook that has the same name.

```
Sub Macro_1()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

For Each x In Application.Workbooks

If x.Name Like "Gonzales*" Then .Activate
Range("A3:A13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Nates Excel.xlsm").Activate
Range("E2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Next x
```

Comment: I tried that as well and it did not work.

Comment: `Then .Activate` won't work outside of a `With... End With` block. Try `Then x.Activate` instead. Also you probably don't want the single-line version of `If`

Comment: How do you have two workbooks saved with the same name? Different folders I assume?  Also the way you have your `IF` statement, is it'll either activate, or not, the `Gonzales*` workbook but *will* select the range `A3:a13` and do the rest of the code. Is that what you intended?